# Nodes of the Dynkin diagram for even-dimensional orthogonal groups

Tags: lie-groups, simple-groups

I'm reading Wilson's book "The Finite Simple Groups", specifically the sections on the orthogonal groups.  (See: http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-84800-988-2)

[In section 3.7.4](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/839/chp%253A10.1007%252F978-1-84800-988-2_3.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fchapter%2F10.1007%2F978-1-84800-988-2_3&token2=exp=1461952693~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F839%2Fchp%25253A10.1007%25252F978-1-84800-988-2_3.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Fchapter%252F10.1007%252F978-1-84800-988-2_3*~hmac=d4c18265e0a76f70b9c261872dde36c7bf4f9542538dae4f248812a7aec437dc), he discusses subgroups of the orthogonal groups.

**The Dynkin diagram for the plus-type orthogonal group of dimension $2m$ is $D_m$.**

(To be clear, "plus-type" means the group preserving a form of maximal Witt index $m$.)

Furthermore, **the nodes along the "stem" of $D_m$ correspond to isotropic spaces of dimension $1,2,\ldots,m-2$,** while the remaining 2 nodes correspond to the 2 orbits of $m$-dimensional isotropic spaces under $SO_{2m}^+(q)$.

The correspondence has the property that if you delete a node from the Dynkin diagram, the remaining diagram corresponds to a group which is a Levi complement of the stabilizer of the appropriate isotropic subspace.

My question is:

**Why are $m-1$ dimensional isotropic spaces left out of this?  Are they somehow different from the others?**